# How much hard drive space do I need to install Windows 7 on my Mac via Boot Camp?

Tags: windows-7, boot-camp, macbook-air

I have a Macbook Air and would like to install Windows 7 on it via Boot Camp. How much hard drive space should I make sure to have free before doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minimum for just install is **20gb for x64** and **16gb for x86**.

Beyond that the question is what programs do you intend to run.

Personally, I find that 60GB is decent if you're frugal with your programs (that's photoshop, a few games, and some project files for C++, etc. in my case).

> [Windows 7 System Requirements](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows7/products/system-requirements)
>
> 16 GB available hard disk space (32-bit) or 20 GB (64-bit)

Again, depending on your uses - you could probably get by on 30-40.

**Here is an easy way to save space**

Once installed, click "My Computer" and then Right Click on the white area and select "Properties".  In the pop-up window, select "System Protection" on the left and disable the Windows Restore points.  They are useless and gobble up space.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 7 needs about 16–20 GiB (32 and 64 bit, repsectively) in a fresh install. Also remember to leave some space for applications.